# How to update value with special character in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-00911

I want to update the password having special characters `''?@ @C $4 ABC` (starting two characters are two single quotes) in `Xyz` table.

I am trying the following query

```
UPDATE Xyz set password="''?@ @C $4" where user_no like '%123%';
```

But I am getting error as

```
ORA-00911: invalid charachter
```

Answer (score 1):

The q-quoting mechanism helps in such situations, when you have to work with multiple single quotes within the string.

```
SQL> desc xyz
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USER_NO                                            NUMBER
 PASSWORD                                           VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> select * From xyz;

   USER_NO PASSWORD
---------- --------------------
       123 a

SQL> update xyz set password = q'[''?@ @C $3]' where user_no = 123;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From xyz;

   USER_NO PASSWORD
---------- --------------------
       123 ''?@ @C $3

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you pasting the query from a different editor or IDE ? or Maybe copying from windows applications to Linux? In that case, there may be non-printable characters present. 
If so, you could retype (not copy-paste) the SQL statement and try.

Also, double quotes aren't commonly used in SQL. You may want to replace them with single quotes.

Comment: No, I am not using any IDE. And tried running query by manually typing the query on the terminal.  And I have two single quotes in the string value so I tried double-quotes. But still, it's not working.

Comment: Can you try `UPDATE Xyz set password='''''?@ @C $3' where user_no like '%123%';`

Comment: In Oracle double-quotes are only used for labels like object names, not identifying literal strings.

Comment: Awesome it worked. Can you please explain why it worked?

Comment: Glad to help!  As @pmdba explained, Enclose strings with single quotes. If your string includes a single quote, escape it with a additional `'` ie 2 quotes to represent 1 quote as shown above.   If this or any other answer helped you, do accept and upvote. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers